# Is there a way to synthesize the note with constant volume in Python with Mingus?

Tags: python, fluidsynth

I'm making a little program to help me practice pitch matching.

The idea is to present a note for 4 seconds and count the time until I sing it in pitch.

I'm producing the note like this:

```
from mingus.containers import Note, Bar
from mingus.midi.fluidsynth import play_Bar
from mingus.midi.fluidsynth import init as initialize_synthesizer

sf2_file = '/usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2'
sound_device = 'alsa'
initialize_synthesizer(sf2_file, sound_device)

def main():
    note = Note("C-3",
                velocity=127)
    bar = Bar()
    bar.place_notes(notes=note,
                    duration=1)
    play_Bar(bar=bar,
             bpm=60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is that the note's volume decreases with time. As it will be used as reference, the volume would ideally be constant. Is there a way to do it?